# WCF Data Services Type Could Not Be Found

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to move a WCF Data Service from hosted within VS2010 to a development web server. When I move the code to an IIS7 application, I get this error:

The type 'Aaa.Bbb.Services.ZzzEntities', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

**ZzzEntities.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost
    Language = "C#"
    Factory = "System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory,
               System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
               PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    Service = "Aaa.Bbb.Services.ZzzEntities" %>
```

**ZzzEntities.svc.cs**

```
using Aaa.Bbb.Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Aaa.Bbb.Services {
    public class ZzzEntities:DataService<Domain.EntityFramework.Context> {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;

            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);

            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion =
                DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, `Aaa.Bbb.Services.dll` is compiled and in the \bin directory of the IIS7 web application.

**EDIT**: Following the instructions [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/WCF_The_type_provided_as_the_Service_attribute_could_not_be_found.aspx) I get the following error when trying to create an instance of `ZzzEntities` - System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ZzzEntities' from assembly 'Aaa.Bbb.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Using .NET Reflector I can clearly see that the Aaa.Bbb.Services.dll contains a class called `ZzzEntities` so I'm really lost about why my type can't be created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a conflict between namespaces.  I'm using [Microsoft WCF Data Services 2011 CTP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10694), so I had to add this to my web.config file in `system.web/compilation/assemblies`:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=4.99.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<add assembly="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.99.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```