# "The type could not be found" when running my SmsService.svc file

Tags: wcf

Error message is:

> The type 'EmmEss.SmsServer.SmsService', provided as the Service
>   attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the
>   configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.

Comment: duplicates: [4 years older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739465/deploying-wcf-tutorial-app-on-iis7-the-type-could-not-be-found) + [3 years older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311355/wcf-data-services-type-could-not-be-found) + [2 years older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645863/wcf-service-the-type-provided-as-the-service-attribute-values-could-not-be-fo) + [1 year older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591972/wcf-service-the-type-provided-as-the-service-attribute-values-could-not-be-foun)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying WCF Tutorial App on IIS7: "The type could not be found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739465/deploying-wcf-tutorial-app-on-iis7-the-type-could-not-be-found)